# How can I trigger an image load by clicking other element rather than the image itself (Lazy Load jQuery plugin)?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

In the [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin's documentation (A jQuery plugin that loads images only when an event occurs) says:

> Event can be any jQuery event such as
>   click or mouseover. You can also use
>   your own custom events such as sporty
>   or foobar. Default is to wait until
>   user scrolls down and image appears on
>   the window. To prevent all images to
>   load until their grey placeholder
>   image is clicked you could do:

```
$("img").lazyload({ 
    placeholder : "img/grey.gif",
    event : "click"
});
```

In this case is clicking the image, but how can I trigger the image load by clicking other element rather than the image itself (say an anchor link/button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo page of [jQuery Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) doesn't seem to work to me on FF3.6 on Mac. I was watching the HTTP requests with the Net tab of Firebug and I could see all the images loaded onload.

Maybe it's worth it to check out this plugin called [JAIL](https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL) that works perfectly. If you look at the example2 it's similar to what your looking for.

Your HTML can look like:

```
<img name="img/grey.gif" src="/global/images/blank.gif" width="width" height="height"/>
```

```
<a href"clickable">Click here to load the image</a>
```

and after you import the plugin, you can call the function in this way:

```
$('img').jail({
     event : "click", 
     selector : "a.clickable"
};
```

Answer (score 3):

use `.trigger()`  to fire up the `click` event i.e.,

```
$(function() {

            $("img").lazyload({ 
                placeholder : "img/grey.gif",
                event : "click"
            });                 

            $('#clickme').click(function() {
                $('img').trigger('click');
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion, I have created a lazy load plugin that will run an event if the element comes into view. It is hooked to the scroll event however by using `$.fn.lazyloadanything('load')` it will force all the load events of any elements that are in view. Might not be exactly what you are looking for but might work:

https://github.com/shrimpwagon/jquery-lazyloadanything

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Understood. I am offering my own "code" as a better alternative. I'm not making any money giving away my jQuery plugin for free. I wouldn't consider it a product. I was looking for a more robust "lazy load" plugin and all of them seem to be more geared towards images. I made a new one and I feel it is more applicable in this situation.